# Difference between 'like' and 'alike': - 'The tepees look alike big tents'

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives, vocabulary, complements

Could someone explain why *alike* is not the correct one for this blank?

> They lived in tepees. These were.......(like, alike) big tents.

answer: *like*

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288752/what-are-the-differences-between-like-and-alike) was closed but has a bit of info.

Comment: A **is like** B. A and B are **alike**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *like* is a preposition. It can take a noun phrase as its complement:

1. Bob looked **like his brother**.

In (1) above, the preposition *like* is taking the noun phrase *his brother* as its complement. Some prepositions are intransitive, which means you can use them on their own without a complement:

2. Bob is **out** <s>of the house</s> right now.

In (2) above the preposition *out* is used intransitively. It doesn't have a complement (in old-fashioned grammars *out* would be thought of as an adverb here). The preposition *like*, however, is always transitive. It cannot be used intransitively, without a complement:

1. *Bob looked **like**. [No complement, ungrammatical]
2. *Bob and Bill looked **like**. [No complement, ungrammatical]

In contrast, the word *alike* is not a preposition, but an adjective. Like nearly all other adjectives, *alike* cannot take a noun phrase as a complement:

5. *Bob was alike Bill. [ungrammatical]
6. *Bob and Bill were alike each other. [ungrammatical]

The words *alike* and *like* both mean 'similar', and involve the comparison of two things (or more than two). Because *alike* cannot take a complement, these two things must be mentioned in the subject. This means that the subject must be a plural noun phrase, or be  a conjunction of two noun phrases:

7. *Bob was alike. [singular noun phrase as subject, ungrammatical]
8. Bob and Bill were alike.
9. The twins were alike.

---

**The Original Poster's question**

10. They lived in tepees. These were ____  big tents.

In (10), above the subject of *were* is plural so this would be grammatically compatible with either *like* or *alike* (*alike*, remember, must have a plural subject and cannot have a singular one).
However, the gap there is followed by a noun phrase, which looks like it must be the complement of the missing word. This, then,  rules out the adjective *alike* but is compatible, of course, with the preposition *like.*

Comment: In the final paragraph, I find *the subject of were is plural so this would be grammatically compatible with either like or alike* confusing. Especially since just above it you have *The twins **were alike***, which is obviously fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the word *compatible* means exactly that, that it's fine to use the two together (*alike* and a plural noun phrase subject). I don't understand why that sentence is confusing? Sorry, if I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm not saying it's "wrong". Just that the wording seems / seemed confusing to me. And of course, I already *know* what you're trying to convey, *and* I probably understand English itself better than almost all learners who might be trying to acquire new information here. Just sayin'

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm following through the different tests one would do in a situation like OP's. First test - is subject plural (because as described, if not, it cannot be *alike*). Second, does the word take an object. I don't understand, exactly, why it's confusing - and so it's difficult for me to know how to rephrase. Could you elaborate for me, please, old bean?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wrote this for EL&U, not ELL, and so haven't graded the language.. Some people there decided that the criterion for migration is that a native speaker would know the correct English, as opposed to whether a native speaker could explain *why*, or whether a linguist or other native speaker might find it interesting. Harrumph.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Have had an edit. That any better?

Comment: Because I already *know* what it's gonna tell me, it's difficult for me to remember exactly *why* I found it confusing the first time around. I *think* it's clearer after your edit, but it might just be that my memory of the initial confusion is fading! It probably makes a difference that you weren't originally addressing *learners* - and rightly or wrongly, successfully or otherwise, I do usually *try* to read Answers (not normally *comments*) as if I wasn't a native Anglophone.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  You seem to have gotten derailed by the full stop before "However,". The paragraph could be clarified for you : "In (10), above the subject of "were" is plural so this *could* be grammatically compatible with either **like** or  **alike** (**alike**, remember, must have a plural subject and cannot have a singular one) but the gap there is followed by a noun phrase, which looks like it must be the complement of the missing word, and that rules out the adjective **alike** but is compatible, of course, with the preposition **like**".

Comment: @Tim: I'm pretty sure the mere fact of your "reworking" having italicised ***could*** instead of plain font **would** would have made a difference. If I see italicised *"could"* in such contexts I'm automatically on the alert for ***...but** [that doesn't apply here]*, whereas I don't normally have that specific "parsing trigger" when I see the word "would".